# Element or its ancestors are member of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check whether an element or any of its ancestors are member of a specific class? As fare as I know, `.hasClass`  only checks for the element itself.

```
<div class="myClass">
 <div>
   <div id='myElement'>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id = 'notMyElement'>
</div>


$('myElement').anyAncestorHasClass('myClass') == true;
$('notMyElement').anyAncestorHasClass('myClass') == false;
```

Comment: i think `closest()` does this.

Comment: Can you explain in code format. Please put your HTML

Answer (score 2):

You can check the length of jQuery object returned by [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

From Documentation:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```js
if($('#myElement').closest('.myClass').length) {
  document.write('Class Exists');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
  <div>
    <div id='myElement'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='notMyElement'>
</div>
```